How to ignore a period(.) with regex from an input
I have a problem. I let the user input a "choice", and that choice may have 2 periods in it. I need a way for regex to not use those as a command and treat them like the rest of the input. This will not always have a period, but there is a chance. What I have now is rf'\b{string}\b' where string is the user's input. I am using the user's input, which may be t.v., and searching in a list with it. The list has some items: my_list = ['t.v.', 'chair', 'fridge', etc...]
Letting you know, this is not the same list, just an example. I cannot remove the periods, as they are needed for the request link I'm using to work.
Please and thank you, let me know if you need any more info.
Edit. Here is a closer example:
my_list = ['Chair', 'Game', 'Couch', 'Fridge', 'T.V.', 'Movie']
def my_loop():
  print(', '.join(my_list))
  my_choice = choose_one()

def choose_one():
  string = input('What do you choose?\t')
  pattern = rf'\b{re.escape(string)}\b'
  for choice in my_list:
    if re.match(pattern, choice, re.IGNORECASE):
      return choice # This doesn't get executed, so smth went wrong.

I tried recreating it with a simpler design, but this is all that happens, given the actual list is a lot bigger.

It might be easier to just remove periods from the user input before applying the regex.

@e-motta re.escape isn't working. I tested it with print(re.escape(string)), and it shows the correct escapes, but when I use it to search, it returns nothing.

@JohnGordon I edited it jist now. I cannot remove the periods, or the request link won't work.

casually, you may (also) be interested in difflib and its close matches feature https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches

[Edit] your question with an example that doesn’t work. re.escape is the solution, but you may not be using it correctly. Don’t escape the added \b for example.

You can insert question marks after the periods, which indicates that they are optional.  For example the regex t\.?v\.? will match the string tv and also t.v.

@ti7 That won't work. I will need exact matches to be returned, as I can only accept 1 argument and there are similar items. That is neat though. I'm using regex because of case insensitivity, although if there is another option that can return exact matches whether or not the case is the same, that would work.

@MarkTolonen I am very confused now. It is supposed to be working, but it just isn't finding it with my code. I'll try to include a closer example, but it may look messy. So pardon that.

@MarkTolonen Sorry for pinging again, but I added an example at the bottom. I don't know if this example will have the same problem for sure, because I can't test it rn. It has all the same code though.

That is not a minimal example, because we don't know what the user input is supposed to be...

You need an adaptive word boundary, pattern = rf'(?!\B\w){re.escape(string)}(?!\B\w)'. See the answer.

@WiktorStribiżew That works! I do not understand it at all, even with the comment you linked(probably bc I just picked up regex today), but thank you! I hooe to understand it eventually.

@JohnGordon I did mention that my goal was to allow the user to input and search for T.V..

If you "picked up" the regex today, you won't understand it, you need to study regex for some time to get the gist of what lookarounds are and how they work, and you need to understand the "word boundary" construct, which is so dubious.

Note that re.match must match exactly from the start of the string. Use re.search if the match can be anywhere in the string
